# unscrambling coded message in python

Tags: python, encryption

I have a puzzle I've been trying to solve for a coding project.

I have a scrambled message, scrambled with a substitution cypher.  Pretty simple, basically `a = x, b = e, c = g`, and so on.

I made a swap function, fully operational, works as planned.

```py
def swap(letter1, letter2):
    counter = 0
    letter1List = []
    letter2List = []

    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[counter] == letter1:
            letter1List.append(counter)
        counter += 1
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[counter] == letter2:
            letter2List.append(counter)
        counter += 1

    x = 0
    for i in range(len(letter1List)):
        s[letter1List[x]] = letter2
        x += 1

    x = 0
    for i in range(len(letter2List)):
        s[letter2List[x]] = letter1
        x += 1
```

And I've been trying to get it to work with various FOR loops to generate every possible swap option, hopefully unscrambling the message in at least one of the outputs.

Basically the best idea I have so far is something like this

```py
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
x = 0

for i in range(len(chars)):
    y = 0
    for i in range(len(chars)):
        swap(chars[x], chars[y])
        print(message)
        y += 1
         
    x += 1
```

But as you can expect, this has some errors.  It doesn't unscramble it in even one of the iterations.

Perhaps one of you can take inspiration from a brute force password program. if you don't have the time to answer, don't worry about it.  But if you can help it is appreciated.

Comment: One note at least: it looks like you can use `x` instead of `i` in your outer for loop, as they seem to satisfy the same purpose. I'm also a bit confused: you simply need to take in a string of characters, and replace every character with the corresponding character in the decryption key? If so, you shouldn't have to iterate over the encrypted string more than once.

Comment: The point is I dont know the key.  And bugs aren't the biggest issue, I will look into the x thing though

Comment: So you're trying to determine the key by producing all possible keys and then applying them to the encryption to see which one produces a result?

Comment: There are 26! possible decryption keys. Iterating through all of them will take a very, very long time.

Comment: @Kraigolas, yes, and i cant seem to figure out how to.

Comment: @knosmos exactly hahahaha. If you **wanted** to do that: `list(itertools.permutations("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))` will give you all possible keys, but it will literally not complete in your lifetime haha.

Comment: Is this a caesar cipher? If so, that is a different approach. If not, as knosmos points out, there will be many many combinations to iterate through. I would consider doing a frequency count/vowel substitution to increase your chances of getting the right answer initially. From there, you could regex to see if common words appear with each cipher.

Comment: @knosmos, i cant seem to figure out how many iterations it would take, it seems to me like it would be 26*26 times, but maybe i'm wrong, do you know?

Comment: it seems that it wouldnt take too long as no letter can be repeated

Comment: @JonathanLeibrant 26! as in 26 factorial, 26*25*24*23...3*2*1

Comment: 26! = 26 * 25 * 24 * 23 ... * 1, which is roughly 4E26

Comment: The letter `a` has 26 possible swaps. `b` has 25 (26 minus the one used by `a`). `c` has 24 possibilities, and so on, so there are 26*25*24...3*2*1 possibilities. Without the key this will be very hard to decrypt.

Comment: thanks for your help, it seems i will need a different method, which should be equally fun to solve

Comment: Key Space of Caesar cipher is about 26. Substitution cipher is about 26!  You are better to look for hill climbing or genetic algorithm to break it.

Comment: will look into that

Answer (score 1):

If you do have the key to the cipher, i.e., if you know which letter to map to which letter, it will be best, just to write this up in a dictionary and run the encrypted message through the dict. As strings are immutable and using str.replace would replace too often, it will be best to convert the string to a list first:

```
decryptDict = {"a":"f", "b":"p",...} 
L = list(encryptedMessage)
for i in len(L):
    L[i] = decryptDict[L[i]]
```

If you do not have the key, then brute force is not the best approach, because to bruteforce you would need to create 26!, i.e. 26 * 25 * ... * 2 * 1, dictionaries and read through all possible decryptions (if the encryption is case-sensitive there are even 52! possible mappings, not counting spaces, colons, numbers, question marks etc.).

Then you should try to look at relative frequencies of the encrypted message and of unencrypted texts in order to establish likely candidates. For example if in the encrypted text "x" makes up about 15% of your letters, then it is a likely candidate for "e" and so forth.

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

If `decryption_key` is the key to the cipher where it is simply the string "abcde...xyz" replaced with their corresponding counterparts in the decryption key (eg. "zyx...edcba" if the key is just the reverse of the alphabet), then

```
decrypted_string = "".join([decryption_key[ord(x) - 97] for x in encrypted_string])
```

will produce the result. Now, using your attempted strategy,

```
from itertools import permutations
possible_keys = permutations(list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
```

will produce all possible decryption keys. This simply will not work, it has a complexity O(n!) where n here is 26, the number of letters in the alphabet. Even if somehow this process did work, you never want n! to be the complexity of an algorithm. You should abandon trying to get it to work, and try to reason out a solution, but my above code will produce the results for you, just not in our lifetime.